# Appendix arabic pagenumbering per appendix if more than one page

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

My university demands appendices to omit pagenumbering, except for appendices which are longer than one page. These should be numbered arabically in themselves. At the moment I have just set pagenumbering to gobble for all appendices. How can I automatically enable arabic pagenumbering only for appendices longer than one page?

Comment: How about `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the start of each appendix? It will not put a page number on the first page of the appendix but later pages will be numbered. Or are page numbers started from 1 for each appendix? Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Yes, the first page of each appendix should be numbered too, if there are more.